# prevent Docker from exposing port on host

Tags: docker, iptables

If i start a container using `-p 80` for example, docker will assign a random outbound port.

Everytime Docker assign a port, it also add an iptable rule to open this port to the world, is it possible to prevent this behaviour ?

Note : I am using a nginx load balancer to get the content, I really don't need to have my application associated with two different port.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify both interface and port as follows:

```
-p ip:hostPort:containerPort
```

or

```
-p ip::containerPort
```

Another solution is to run nginx inside container and to use conteiner linking without exposing other services whatsoever.

Comment: is it possible to do -p127.0.0.1:1234 to get a random assigned port ?

Comment: You can use `ip::containerPort`, I've updated an answer.

Comment: I am running nginx inside container btw, but still if i expose like "ContainerPort", the randomHost port got open to the world

Answer (score 0):

The iptable feature is a startup parameter for the docker demon. Look for the docker demon conf file in your docker installation. Add --iptables=false and docker never touches your iptables.